# How to save tkinter widgets with dataclass in a list?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, widget

I am trying to store widgets in a list to save some code lines. My current idea is to add elements to a dataclass, save these elements in a list and then iterate through that list to create widgets from the information stored in the dataclass.

```
import tkinter as tk 
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class elemente():
    name : str = "empty"
    typ : str = "empty"
    row : int = 0
    col : int = 0
    cmd : str = 'no command'
    text : str = 'no Text'

class GUI(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        self.search_btn = elemente(typ='btn', text="search", row=0, col=2, cmd=self.test)
        self.result_btn = elemente(typ='btn', text="results", row=3, col=2, cmd=self.test)
        self.list_main = [self.search_btn, self.result_btn]
        self.add_elements(self.list_main)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)  

    def add_elements(self, cur_list):
        for elem in cur_list:
            if elem.typ == 'btn':
                elem = tk.Button(text = elem.text, command = elem.cmd)
                elem.grid(row = elem.row, column = elem.col)
    def test(self):
       pass

root = tk.Tk()
gui = GUI(master = root)
gui.mainloop()
```

**Error message:**

AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'row'

Normally I would access the information with:
self.search_btn.typ, etc. which does work. The problem seems to be with storing the buttons in self.list_main. Does anyone know the reason for this, or is there a different way to store many buttons, text widgets in a list?

Comment: You overwrite `elem = ` with object `Button(...`, rename it to `button = tk.Button(...`

Comment: You are right. It was overwriting it. Simply using elem.name instead of elem as the name fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you should add to self like following:

```
def add_elements(self, cur_list):
        for elem in cur_list:
            if elem.typ == 'btn':
                self.elem = tk.Button(text = elem.text, command = elem.cmd)
                self.elem.grid(row = elem.row, column = elem.col)
```